# Check the Subscriber Consent Before sending an Email

Tags: marketing-cloud, community, ampscript, marketing-cloud-connect, send-email

When any Email Campaign is send from the Marketing cloud, I want to check the latest Subscriber Consent for Email_Optin from the Master_lead DE which is Sync with CRM.

If the Email_Optin is not true then it should raise the error and save the details in 'RaiseError_SendLog_DE' DE.

Below code throws an error when I am trying to Preview Email but when I actual send the email it is cancelled and is not deployed.

```
/** Consent OptIn**/
set @RaiseError_Flag = 'False'
set @JobID = JobID
set @ListID = ListID
set @BatchID = _JobSubscriberBatchID
set @SubID = Id

set @Error_DE = 'RaiseError_SendLog_DE'
set @Master_Lead = 'Webinar_test'
set @numRowsToReturn = 0

set @Crows = LookupOrderedRows(@Master_Lead,@numRowsToReturn,'Id', 'Id', @SubID)
set @Crowcount = rowcount(@Crows)

IF @Crowcount == 0 THEN
   set @RaiseError_Flag = 'True'
   set @SL_MiscData = CONCAT(@SL_MiscData, 'No Optin Status')
ELSE
  set @MCEmailOptIn__c = Field(Row(@Crows,1),'MCEmailOptIn__c')
     IF @MCEmailOptIn__c != 'True' THEN
         set @RaiseError_Flag = 'True'
         set @SL_MiscData = CONCAT(@SL_MiscData, 'status=', Trim(@Optin_Status))
         
    ENDIF
ENDIF


IF @RaiseError_Flag == 'True' THEN
   set @SL_MiscData = SUBSTRING(CONCAT('Consent Raise Error!', @SL_MiscData), 1, 150)
   
   InsertDE(@Error_DE, 'JobID', @JobID, 'ListID', @ListID, 'BatchID', @BatchID, 'SubID', @SubID, 'SL_Subscriber_key', @SL_Subscriber_key, 'SL_MiscData', @SL_MiscData, 'ErrorCode', @ErrorCode, 'SL_Email_Address', @SL_Email_Address, 'Created_Date', @Created_Date,)
   
   RaiseError("Do not Send to subscriber - Consent not available or true", True)
   
ENDIF
```

Comment: I would not recommend this approach for suppressing subscribers in a send.  Inserts in emails are batched until the end of a send.  Plus, you still get charged for a send if you skip it via raiseError.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Above script I'm able to raise an error and save the error values in DE:

```
/** Consent OptIn Start **/
set @RaiseError_Flag = 'False'
set @JobID = JobID
set @ListID = ListID
set @BatchID = _JobSubscriberBatchID
set @SubID = Id

set @Error_DE = 'RaiseError_SendLog_DE'
set @Master_Lead_Data = 'Webinar_test'
set @numRowsToReturn = 0

set @Crows = LookupOrderedRows(@Master_Lead_Data,@numRowsToReturn,'Id', 'ID', @SubID)
set @Crowcount = rowcount(@Crows)

IF @Crowcount == 0 THEN
   set @RaiseError_Flag = 'True'
   set @SL_MiscData = CONCAT(@SL_MiscData, 'No Optin Status')
ELSE
  set @MCEmailOptIn__c = Field(Row(@Crows,1),'MCEmailOptIn__c')
     IF @MCEmailOptIn__c != 'True' THEN
         set @RaiseError_Flag = 'True'
         set @SL_MiscData = CONCAT(@SL_MiscData, 'status=', Trim(@MCEmailOptIn__c))
         
    ENDIF
ENDIF

IF @RaiseError_Flag == 'True' THEN
   set @SL_MiscData = SUBSTRING(CONCAT('Consent Raise Error!', @SL_MiscData), 1, 150)
   InsertDE(@Error_DE,"SL_Subscriber_key",@SubID,"JobID",@JobID,"SL_MiscData",@SL_MiscData,"SL_Email_Name", emailname_)
   
   RaiseError("Do not Send to subscriber - Consent not available or true", true, "Email Failed Validation", "7000", 1)
   
ENDIF
/** Consent OptIn End **/
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend creating an [Exclusion Script](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000339899&type=1) content block in Content Builder and adding your logic to that, then in your email's send definition, add an AMPscript  conditional that returns `true` or `false`.

There are multiple examples floating around on how to do that.  Here's [one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/296531/5202).

Perhaps you can update your question to clarify the need for creating a log for subscribers that are skipped.